# How to read a txt file using echo command in bash

Tags: bash, echo

here is a part of my script. I would like to display the contents of the file repo.txt in the echo command before performing any option. Can somebody please help me to find what option goes in echo line to display the file contents ?

```
file="repo.txt"
    echo "Do you really want to delete the repos: $file "
    read options
    echo "Option Selected Is $options"
    if [ $options == "yes" ]
    then
```

Comment: simpler to use directly `cat repo.txt` or `cat $file`. And when file is longer and you need pagination `more $file` or `less $file`

Comment: on similar portal for [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) I found this: [How can I display the contents of a text file on the command line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86321/how-can-i-display-the-contents-of-a-text-file-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readarray -t repos < repo.txt
echo "Do you really want to delete the repos:"
printf " - %s\n" "${repos[@]}"
read -p "Answer [y/n]: " ANSWER
if [ "$ANSWER" = "yes" -o "$ANSWER" = "y" ];then
   echo remove
else
   echo skipp
fi


$ ./script.sh
Do you really want to delete the repos:
 - repo1
 - repo2
 - repo3
 - repo4
 - repo5
 - repo6
Answer [y/n]: y
remove
```

Answer (score 2):

Swap:

```
echo "Do you really want to delete the repos: $file "
```

for

```
echo "Do you really want to delete the repos: $(cat $file)"
```

Comment: in bash you can replace `$(cat "$file")` with `$(<"$file")`